# Correct symbology for use in integrals of surfaces (or of line): explanations

Tags: integration, definition, surfaces, surface-integrals

The question is very simple and it is only related to the actual mathematical notation. I remember that I read many books and each one uses its own notation.

Let $\overline{F}$ (or $\mathbf{F}$) a vectorial field. When I write an integral of surface (where $S$ it is a general surface), what is the correct usual notation

$$\int_S \overline{F} \cdot \overline{da}\iff \int_S \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{da} \tag 1$$

or is it must be of this type?

$$\int_S \overline{F} \cdot d\ \bar{a}\iff \int_S \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{d} a \tag 2$$

If exist a difference between $(1)$ and $(2)$ what are the differences?

PS: The same question for integrals of line.

Comment: I think for the second you want the $a$ in boldface. Don't you also want vector arrows instead of overlines?

Comment: Anyway, they all seem fine to me. There isn't necessarily a 'best' way to typeset these, it depends a lot on personal preference.

Comment: @LucasL. Thank you for your kind answer I generally use the \overline symbol instead of the classic vector symbol.